# Remove shipping information from Email template if method is "freeshipping"

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, email-templates

How to remove or hide a shipping information in Email template `order_new.html` if the shipping method is **freeshipping**, i named it "Shop pick up" so we don't need to display this information because there is no shipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by below code.

Create an observer function which will check if order has "Free Shipping" in your case "Shop pick up" method selected.

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_before>
        <observers>
            <update_order_for_free_shipping>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>updateOrderForFreeShipping</method>
            </update_order_for_free_shipping>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_before>
</events>
```

Now create **Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer 
{
    public function updateOrderForFreeShipping($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->getShippingMethod() == 'freeshipping_freeshipping' ? $order->setHideFreeShipping(false) : $order->setHideFreeShipping(true);
    }
}
```

Now update your **order_new.html** file and replace

```
{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
<td class="method-info">
    <h6>Shipping method:</h6>
    <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
</td>
{{/depend}}
```

With

```
{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
{{if order.hide_free_shipping}}
<td class="method-info">
    <h6>Shipping method:</h6>
    <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
</td>
{{/if}}
{{/depend}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaimin, nobody was able to do it except you ;)